# Flickity.js gallery crashes on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flickity

I am trying to load a simple js based gallery - [Flickity.js](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

As per mentioned in the example, i tried loading up the gallery which works perfectly fine .

But randomly, the gallery crashes upon page load:

[image]

the code that i use to initiate the gallery:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.main-carousel').flickity({
        // options
        cellAlign: 'left',
        contain: true,
        pageDots: false,
    });
</script>
```

I do understand that this maybe related to the document (images not loading) at the time the script is initiated so as a result , i tried including the document.ready function which infact throws another error .

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.main-carousel').flickity({
            // options
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true,
            pageDots: false,
        });
});
```

the outcome of this is, it shows flickity is not a function.

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

since `$(document).ready` is fired only when DOM (HTML) is loaded.

**Edit**: Also, since you are using Juicer.io/embedjs, you should import it before Flickity, since it contains JQuery already (and remove the standalone JQuery import):

```
<script src="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.carousel').flickity({
            // options
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true,
            pageDots: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pycfs5e8/

If you still need to import JQuery for some reason, you can also use Embed with no JQuery version (not tested):

```
<script src="//assets.juicer.io/embed-no-jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: tried the same , the issue remains .

`<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.main-carousel,.gallery,.related-topics').flickity({
            // options
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true,
            pageDots: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: Are you importing the libraries in order? 1st JQuery, 2nd Flickity, 3rd your script. Like this https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/yyvXYL

Comment: Hey there , i found that the issue is with this library - Juicer.io

`<script src="https://assets.juicer.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

how do i find what is causing the issue ? 

When i remove this , flickity is being initailzed properly .

Comment: Have a look at the source code here : [link](www.shadesproperties.ae)

Comment: You can create a JSFiddle replicating your problem. Couldnt find anything in a minified code

Comment: have a look at this - jsfiddle.net/eq42xsfy/3